# Are questions about online chess and Internet chess clients on topic?

Tags: discussion

Internet chess clients and servers/sites can be fairly complicated (see [BabasChess](http://www.babaschess.net/)). Is this site an appropriate place to look for help on using such things?

Example potential question: "Which FICS clients support Linux and can automatically create PGNs of games?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those questions are absolutely on topic here.

Comment: What about a question like, "How to delete a chessbase.com account"?